# ACCESS acViewPreview not working as intended

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to print preview my report (using a button on my form, see code below). When I go to do it initially, it pops up as a super small image, and I cannot right click it (so I cannot print or export it).

[image]

However, after simply entering Design View (but not changing anything), then opening the form to print the report again, it works as intended (i.e. pops up at a normal size and I can now right click the report).

```
Private Sub Report_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "Query1", acViewPreview, , Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter

End Sub
```

Any idea why this may be happening? What could be happening that simply going into Design View, then back to Form View, is changing how the report opens?

Comment: Maybe code? [Me.Move 10,10,10,10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.move) would size pop-üp to 10x10 [twips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#twip), `Me.Move 0,0,1000,1000` in Report_Load will make it grow.

Comment: Aside from the size, the "real" issue is that I cannot right click the report to print or export it. It's a real strange problem!

Comment: Do ribbons for print (file),export work?

Comment: Do you mean on the report itself? There are no ribbons or functionality of any kind (until I go in and out of Design View, then I can right click print etc.).

Comment: Try the default tabs,  File -> Print and External Data -> Export